# Get a custom field of all posts on current blog page

Tags: posts, custom-field

I am trying to get a custom field value from all posts listed on current blog paginated page. Not sure if it's clear, let me explain it more.

On blog index page (or on second page of pagination) I have 10 posts. And each post have a value for custom field **my-field**. So I want to list posts as it is but outside the post list (lets say in footer.php) I want to also list all the values of custom field **my-field** belonging to current posts.

Not sure exactly how it can be done.

**EDIT**

To simplify (for understanding), I want to echo posts IDs of all listed posts in footer.php.

Comment: Create a `global` variable, load all the custom values there, you could use an array. Then just call that var in the footer and do what you have to do

Comment: Thanks @TomásCot, yes it will work I think. Just started working in this direction. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just rewind the query to loop through again:

```
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <p>Post Number: <?php the_ID(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

[THE LOOP](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: I do have to say though that Pieter's answer is more versatile. Up-vote to him.

Comment: Yes, but I ended up using @TomásCot suggestion because it provides lots of flexibility. And don't need to worry about custom queries too. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to get all the ID's. The `$wp_query` global is available as the main query has already executed, so can just access the `$posts` property and from there get your post ID's. Something like this will do

```
global $wp_query;
$posts = $wp_query->posts;
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo $post->ID;
}
```

If you need an array of ID's, do the following

```
global $wp_query;
$posts = $wp_query->posts;

$ids = [];
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $ids[] = $post->ID;
}

?><pre><?php var_dump($ids); ?></pre><?php
```

All your post ID's will be held in the `$ids` variable